# Logback causes thread freezing when logging from child process

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I met strange issue with logback, that FREEZE thread when trying to log in a spawned child java process. Briefly described as below:

- ParentProcess creates 1 ChildProcess
- In ChildProcess, use logback prints 1000 lines.

Note:

- Logging is output to Console
- App freeze
- Issue not happen when: Run directly ChildProcess (without ParentProcess); or log to File only (no Console log)

I push simple code that produce this phenomenom: https://github.com/huymluu/logbackfreeze

**EDIT: add thread dump**

```
"process reaper@687" daemon prio=10 tid=0xc nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(UNIXProcess.java:-1)
      at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$initStreams$3(UNIXProcess.java:290)
      at java.lang.UNIXProcess$$Lambda$7.687241927.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:396)
      at parent.ParentProcess.main(ParentProcess.java:20)

"Finalizer@689" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler@690" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"Signal Dispatcher@688" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, looks like `System.out.println` deadlock or something. Could you please add a thread dump after the app freezes? One for the ParentProcess and one for the ChildProcess. It would be a lot of threads for the ChildProcess, but most of them should be pretty much the same; we need the unique stack-traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think logback has problem with child process's console output. Just don't know the detail why it happened.

Trying to redirect child process's output will solve this issue. e.g. use `redirectOutput()` of `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(new File("/dev/null"));
```

Comment: Also ran into this problem with logback 1.2.3. Your solution helps me too. Thank you!